# Where can I find a non-ARC version of CocoaAsyncSocket?

Tags: macos, cocoa, asyncsocket

I have an application that I have used AsyncSocket with success, but the application is required to run on 32-bit Mac systems so I'd like a non-ARC version of AsyncSocket. In my searching I am finding indications that AsyncSocket was indeed non-ARC in earlier versions but I cannot find any site that has archives of older versions. GitHub only seems to have an ARC version. Does anyone know where I can find a non-ARC version?

Edit: nevermind, I scrolled back through github commits and can get what I need.

Comment: Doesn't git have the whole project history?

Comment: I think you're right. I scrolled back through the history a ways and I think I can get a non-ARC version.

Comment: Why not post a link to an old version as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

New answer to an old question, but in case anyone's wondering, CocoaAsyncSocket was converted to ARC in 7.1. Grab the latest 7.0.x for non-ARC.

More info on the wiki: [link](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/ARC)